systemd-cryptsetup LUKS Encryption key storage
I have 3 LUKS-encrypted partitions, but I only need to enter decryption password once. I am curious where Anaconda & Blivet have saved the other two passwords. I may need to know that in case I forget those, can't access my password storage & need to examine those partitions from another OS. I also want to save my second drive LUKS password somewhere system-wide so it will be unlocked on boot for all users.
Where I have looked already:

/etc/crypttab doesn't mention any key files
/etc/lusk-keys/ doesn't exist
/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/ doesn't exits
I can't see anything LUKS-related in tpm

There are systemd-cryptsetup related logs in journalctl -b for multiple LUKS devices.
Where are the keys stored for LUKS partitions generated in Blivet after setup? Where does systemd-cryptsetup store LUKS keys? Maybe the keys are somehow stored in initramfs? But how do I inspect that?

So it's not just the same passphrase for all?

@frostschutz It is, but I want to understand why it doesn't ask me to enter all 3. And how it knows not to ask.

Probably some variation of systemd-ask-password --accept-cached or similar implementation that re-uses passwords. If you don't mind luksChangeKey, see if it asks you if you change it to something else. (Backup the LUKS header first, also add another backup passphrase, just in case.)
